# weird float to int when moving a var

Tags: php

Here's my code, fetch_data.php returns a float (an exchange rate).
The first echo will return the float that I need (0.65 something) but the second one will return an integer (1)... Why? How do I fix this?

I'm using include because file_get_contents returned PHP for some reason? I don't have a lot of PHP experience and haven't written a line in a month so I'm rusty.

```
        <div class="callout panel">
          <p><strong>We sell for:</strong> $<?php  

          $coin_price = include('fetch_data.php'); 
          $doge = $coin_price;


          echo $coin_price;  
          echo $doge;

          ?> per 1000</p>
        </div>
```

fetch data

```
    $string = strip_tags($element); //<strong>$484.66</strong>
    $string = str_replace('$', '', $string);
    $int = $string;

    $val = $int * 1.25;

    echo $val / 1000;
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the source for fetch_data.php?
What you'll probably want to do is include fetch_data.php and run a function from that file, assigning a value to $coin_price.

Comment: You are not supposed to use include like that.

Comment: @JoniSalmi Why does file get contents returns PHP code?

Comment: The problem is probably not where you suspect. Maybe something gets echoed in your include file. You should get '$0.650.65 per 1000' if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @Anustart Use `return $val / 1000;` instead of `echo $val / 1000;` However, your overall code design is awful.

Comment: File get content just returns files content as it is. It's ssupposed to work like that

Comment: 'include' is not a function that returns a value. 'include' behaves as if you would copy the source code of the included file at this place.

Comment: @Anustart I hope you'll rethink your design too.

Comment: I removed the whole include() business. I'm not a programmer, I just play around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$doge = floatval($coin_price);
```

Check here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 0):

fetch_data.php

```
$string = strip_tags($element); //<strong>$484.66</strong>
$string = str_replace('$', '', $string);
$int = $string;

$val = $int * 1.25;

$coin_price = $val / 1000;
```

other php file

```
<div class="callout panel">
    <p><strong>We sell for:</strong> 
       $<?php  
           include('fetch_data.php'); 

           echo $coin_price;  
           $doge = $coin_price;
           echo $doge;
      ?> per 1000</p>
</div>
```

I modified the code a bit if you want to use `include` like you are currently.  When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward.